# Add labels or text to tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to add labels or more text/data ( unrelated to x,y coordinates) when hovering on the data points in C3

I am not sure if such function is possible with c3

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    onReady('#chart', function() {
      var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
          x: 'x',
          //        xFormat: '%Y%m%d', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x'
          columns: [
            ['x', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-04', '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06'],
            //            ['x', '20130101', '20130102', '20130103', '20130104', '20130105', '20130106'],
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350],
            ['data3', 70, 220, -200, 100, 600, 512]
          ],
          types: {
            data1: 'line',
            data2: 'line',
            data3: 'bar'
          },
          labels: {
            format: {
              data1: d3.format()
            }

          }

        },
        grid: {
          x: {
            show: false
          },
          y: {
            lines: [{
              value: 0
            }, {
              color: 'red'
            }]
          }
        },
        axis: {
          x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
              format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });

    // Set a timeout so that we can ensure that the `chart` element is created.
    function onReady(selector, callback) {
      var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (document.querySelector(selector) !== undefined) {
          window.clearInterval(intervalID);
          callback.call(this);
        }
      }, 500);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I expected the same chart, but with either labels ('A', 'B','C','D','E','F') as additional text inside the hover tooltip, or as labels next to the points.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 "tooltip": {
        'contents': function () {
            return "<div>Test</div>";
        }
    },
```

For future reference, I ended going with this solution, and I have yet to prettify the html to get what I want.

Also .d3 can be included into css as follows:

```
d3-tip {
  line-height: 
  background-color: 
  font-weight: 
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: rgba(#,#,#,#); 
  color: magenta;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```